# How to load a class from its source code using Javassist?

Tags: java, javassist, javaloader

I have in an input stream the complete source code of a class. Is it possible to use Javassist to create a new `CtClass` object for this class ?.

I know that with the name of the class is possible to create a new `CtClass` object with something like:

```
ClassPool.getDefault().makeClass("name_of_the_new_class");
```

But in my case I do not know the name of the class in advance, but just its complete source code (of course I could get the name of the class parsing the source code, but please do not tell me that this is part of the solution :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compile a source file on-the-fly, have a look at the tools API as well as [ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler%28%29).  From there you can compile .class files from source and load them using a classloader if you need to.

You could also then use Javassist to create a CtClass from the bytes of the created class file using [ByteArrayClassPath](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/ByteArrayClassPath.html) with a new ClassPool.